# Why does this London Underground poster from 1924 have a Star of David atop a Christmas tree?

Tags: 20th-century, religion, britain, art, propaganda

There is currently [an exhibit at the Art Institute of Chicago](https://www.artic.edu/exhibitions/8932/everyone-s-art-gallery-posters-of-the-london-underground) displaying posters promoting London Underground transit from the 1920's and 30's.

This interesting piece comes from **1924**.  A full descripton can be seen on [The Library of Congress website.](https://www.loc.gov/pictures/item/2010650634/)  As you can see, it is somewhat unusual in that, despite including a Christmas tree and the word "Christmas," it has a Star of David atop the tree.

[image]

The blending of Jewish and Christian traditions in early 20th century Britain surprised me.  To my knowledge, placing a star atop a Christmas tree is a common form of decoration, but the specific reference to Judaism seems unusual.

Is there any precedent for this kind of cross-cultural decor?  Was it in fact designed for inclusivity?  Or, alternatively, was placing a Star of David atop a Christmas tree once a common practice in the mainstream Christian tradition, in Britain or elsewhere?

Comment: @IanRingrose Maybe becuase Judaism does not recognise him as such?

Comment: @Angew think of the target of the advert and what songs most of the targets would be singing at Christmas

Comment: The person who designed this just put a star on top that came to mind? In that case, we will never know.

Comment: @JanDoggen Not to mention that 6 point stars are far easier to draw than 5 point stars.

Comment: On a side note, I found it curious that it says "A Merrie Christmas" which, according to some cursory searches went out of favor when Q. Elizabeth II started saying "Happy Christmas" in radio broadcasts.

Comment: @JimmyJames Merry/ie Christmas and its variants are still widely used in the UK, If not more than Happy Christmas

Comment: @JimmyJames The British don't all talk like the Queen, and rarely say 'Happy Christmas'. Instead they say 'Merry Christmas' and 'Happy New Year'. The Merrie spelling is odd (even I suspect for Cooper's era). But I guess he/they just thought it looked a bit ye-olde-worlde, or just a bit nicer as a graphic on the page. That said, one is encountering something of an annus horibilis.

Comment: @Strawberry Somehow I got it in my head that the saying "Merry Christmas" was considered a silly American thing to do.  Thanks.

Comment: It may be. Recent events should satisfy us that Brits are not beyond being very, very silly.

Comment: Related [Do Christmas celebrations have these diverse non-Christian origins?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/13877/45610)

Answer (score 101, accepted):

The hexagram [is not an exclusively Jewish symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexagram#Usage_by_the_Abrahamic_religions).  For that matter, the [Star of David](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_of_David) as a symbol of Judaism (as opposed to a symbol *used by* Jews) is far newer than people realize, dating only to 1897 and the [First Zionist Congress](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_Zionist_Congress).  Given that, seeing a six-pointed star on top of a Christmas tree in 1924 is no surprise.

Also, Jesus was of the house of David, so the Star of Bethlehem being designed as a Star of David should be especially unsurprising

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97934/discussion-on-answer-by-mark-why-does-this-london-underground-poster-from-1924-h).

Comment: +1. Here's a 1930s [Ukrainian Christmas post-card](https://risu.org.ua/php_uploads/images/articles/ArticleImages_69520_IMG_9921.jpg), a child is holding a traditional Ukrainian Christmas pole with a star which is a hexagram with XP inside it. The text is "Look with your kind eye, Oh the Son of God, down unto our land, Ukraine..."